# How to use p5.loadImage in Vue 3

Tags: p5.js, vuejs3

The [p5 docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) state how to load an image from the assets folder.

However I am using 'instance mode' in my Vue 3 setup and any attempt to use loadImage is resulting in the return of an Event object of type"error" and no explanation.

I have tried:

```
const script = p5 => {
    ...
    this.assets.rocket = p5.loadImage('./assets/rocket.jpg')
    this.assets.rocket = p5.loadImage('~assets/rocket.jpg')
    this.assets.rocket = p5.loadImage('@/assets/rocket.jpg')
}
```

and so on.

I know the image exists as `<img src="./assets/rocket.jpg">` renders the image correctly.

What have I missed?

(Everything else regarding p5 in instance mode appears to be working fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `p5.loadImage(require('@/assets/rocket.jpg'))`?

Importing image should be a Webpack responsibility, not p5.js